# macOS Monterey refuses to open Bitcoin Core.app because Apple cannot check it for malicious software

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac

Today I upgraded to macOS Monterey. First, the new OS deleted "Bitcoin Core.app". So, I re-downloaded the signed .dmg. Second, Monterey refused to open "Bitcoin Core.app" saying

> "Bitcoin Core.app" can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.

BTW. I'm not used to compiling C++ code as I am not a C++ programmer but I have xCode installed on my macOS.

Answer (score 2):

Okay! The old way still works:

1. In the Finder on your Mac, locate the app you want to open.
2. Control-click the app icon, then choose Open from the shortcut menu.
3. Click Open.